# Sending a stream of data from UWP to WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, uwp

I have created a WCF service, which exposes the following `[OperationContract]`:

```
Task<bool> SendStream(Stream stream);
```

If I connect to this service from a WPF app, I can use the method as expected. However I want to send the data from a UWP app, and when trying to do so I find that the UWP client connection expects me to send a `byte[]` and not a `Stream`.

Why will UWP not recognise `Stream`, and how can I get around it? For reference I am intending to send files that could be many hundreds of MB in size, hence the reason I want to stream them.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: I've helped you report this issue on [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/3220). Let's wait their response.

Comment: Many thanks @XavierXie-MSFT!